# Camunda Application not starting up on docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, camunda

I have a simple `cammunda` spring boot application. which I want to run in a docker container

I am able to run it locally from `IntelliJ` but when I try to run it inside a docker it fails with below error message:

> 08043 Exception while performing 'Deployment of Process Application
> camundaApplication' => 'Deployment of process archive 'ct-camunda':
> The deployment contains definitions with the same key 'ct-camunda' (id
> attribute), this is not allowed

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  myaap:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

**processes.yml**

```
<process-application xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/ProcessApplication">

    <process-engine name="my-engine">
        <configuration>org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration</configuration>
    </process-engine>

    <process-archive name="ct-camunda" tenantId="ct-camunda">
        <process-engine>default</process-engine>
        <resource>ct-camunda.bpmn</resource>
        <properties>
            <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
            <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
        </properties>
    </process-archive>

</process-application>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/camunda-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Main class **CamundaApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableProcessApplication
public class CamundaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamundaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error logs:

```
2022-02-25 03:21:24.724  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08023 Deployment summary for process archive 'ct-camunda': 


        ct-camunda.bpmn

        BOOT-INF/classes/ct-camunda.bpmn


2022-02-25 03:21:25.067 ERROR 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.context           : ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: The deployment contains definitions with the same key 'ct-camunda' (id attribute), this is not allowed


org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: The deployment contains definitions with the same key 'ct-camunda' (id attribute), this is not allowed

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.ensureNoDuplicateDefinitionKeys(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:192) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.deploy(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:65) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:54) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:51) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:559) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:547) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer.deploy(CacheDeployer.java:51) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:71) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:64) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.deploy(DeployCmd.java:254) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.lambda$doExecute$0(DeployCmd.java:155) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:559) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:547) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.doExecute(DeployCmd.java:141) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:101) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:81) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:72) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandCounterInterceptor.execute(CommandCounterInterceptor.java:35) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.deployWithResult(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deployWithResult(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:270) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:266) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.ProcessApplicationDeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(ProcessApplicationDeploymentBuilderImpl.java:63) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.deployment.DeployProcessArchiveStep.performOperationStep(DeployProcessArchiveStep.java:146) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:120) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.executeDeploymentOperation(MBeanServiceContainer.java:160) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation$DeploymentOperationBuilder.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:216) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.deployProcessApplication(RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.java:102) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.application.AbstractProcessApplication.deploy(AbstractProcessApplication.java:71) ~[camunda-engine-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.start(SpringProcessApplication.java:110) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.afterPropertiesSet(SpringProcessApplication.java:119) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.SpringBootProcessApplication.afterPropertiesSet(SpringBootProcessApplication.java:102) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:96) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:52) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.SpringBootProcessApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$595e572.onApplicationEvent(<generated>) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]

at com.nk.ct.camunda.CamundaApplication.main(CamundaApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]


2022-02-25 03:21:25.090  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14015 Shutting down the JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor]

2022-02-25 03:21:25.091  INFO 1 --- [ultJobExecutor]] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14020 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] stopped job acquisition

2022-02-25 03:21:25.111  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'decision.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.decision.engine.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.126  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'decision.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.decision.history.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.138  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'case.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.case.engine.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.185  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.engine.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'case.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.case.history.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.224  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.history.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.233  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'drop' on component 'identity' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/drop/activiti.h2.drop.identity.sql'

2022-02-25 03:21:25.236  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine                   : ENGINE-00007 Process Engine my-engine closed

2022-02-25 03:21:25.250  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

2022-02-25 03:21:25.265  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2022-02-25 03:21:25.303 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed


java.lang.RuntimeException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-08043 Exception while performing 'Deployment of Process Application camundaApplication' => 'Deployment of process archive 'ct-camunda': The deployment contains definitions with the same key 'ct-camunda' (id attribute), this is not allowed

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:105) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:52) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.SpringBootProcessApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$595e572.onApplicationEvent(<generated>) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-7.16.0.jar!/:7.16.0]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is Docker related. Maybe your build process copies files?

*"The deployment contains definitions with the same key 'ct-camunda' (id attribute), this is not allowed"*
Check if you have packaged multiple .bpmn files into your deployment. Maybe you accidentally copied the model file in an additional classpath location. You seem to have two deployments with the same id. (This is not about the filename, but the technical id used inside the XML)

If you are using auto deployment in Spring Boot, you do not have to declare anything in the processes.xml. Use this only in combination with @EnableProcessApplication (or do not use both)

Comment: I am only copying jar in docker build process(added `Dockerfile` & `Main Class` in the question). I am still not clear why this works fine while running with `intelliJ`

Comment: Take all BPMN and DMN files out of your project. Clean build. In in Intelli you should then have a runtime without model. Then try the docker deployment again. It should work. Next deploy the models from Modeler. This should also work. Then see what happens if you add those model files back (not required).